# Fast selection of a time interval in a pandas DataFrame/Series

Tags: python, indexing, pandas

my problem is that I want to filter a DataFrame to only include times within the interval *[start, end)* . If do not care about the day, I would like to filter only for start and end time for each day. I have a solution for this but it is slow. So my question is if there is a faster way to do the time based filtering.

Example

```
import pandas as pd
import time


index=pd.date_range(start='2012-11-05 01:00:00', end='2012-11-05 23:00:00', freq='1S').tz_localize('UTC')
df=pd.DataFrame(range(len(index)), index=index, columns=['Number'])

# select from 1 to 2 am, include day
now=time.time()
df2=df.ix['2012-11-05 01:00:00':'2012-11-05 02:00:00']
print 'Took %s seconds' %(time.time()-now) #0.0368609428406

# select from 1 to 2 am, for every day
now=time.time()
selector=(df.index.hour>=1) & (df.index.hour<2)
df3=df[selector]
print 'Took %s seconds' %(time.time()-now) #Took  0.0699911117554
```

As you can see if I remove the day (second case) it takes almost twice as much. The computation time increases rapidly if I have a number of different days, e.g from 5 to 7 Nov:

```
index=pd.date_range(start='2012-11-05 01:00:00', end='2012-11-07 23:00:00', freq='1S').tz_localize('UTC')
```

So, to summarize is there a faster method to filter by time of the day, across many days?

Thx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need `between_time` method.

```
In [14]: %timeit df.between_time(start_time='01:00', end_time='02:00')
100 loops, best of 3: 10.2 ms per loop

In [15]: %timeit selector=(df.index.hour>=1) & (df.index.hour<2); df[selector]
100 loops, best of 3: 18.2 ms per loop
```

I had done these tests with 5th to 7th November as index.

#### Documentation

```
Definition: df.between_time(self, start_time, end_time, include_start=True, include_end=True)
Docstring:
Select values between particular times of the day (e.g., 9:00-9:30 AM)

Parameters
----------
start_time : datetime.time or string
end_time : datetime.time or string
include_start : boolean, default True
include_end : boolean, default True

Returns
-------
values_between_time : type of caller
```

Comment: would u like to do a PR to add a small section to timeseries.rst for usage such as this?

Comment: Thx, by the way, is there something similar for selecting an interval of days, e.g. all times belonging to a specified set of days? I can of course filter by index=(df.index.date==a_date) but this turns out to be very slow...

Comment: @Jeff: A bit swamped currently, won't be able to submit a PR soon. Also, working on a project with 0.12; so will take some time to come to dev till sure everything works fine on upgrade. Do you have an answer to the above comment..Something like `between_date`?

Comment: ``df.query("index >= start_date & index <= end_date")`` should work (start/end dates can be strings or Timestamps/datetimes)

Comment: the query approach has some issues with the timezone, e.g. I use tz_convert to convert to 'Europe/Berlin', but the query acts as if the time was in UTC (this was the original time of the series, imposed with tz_localize). The results is that time filtered time series starts at 1 am (which is 0 am in UTC time) rather than 0 am (which is 23 pm UTC time the previous day), so the basis for the filtering is UTC time, even if I converted to UTC+1 hour...

Comment: ok, with pd.Timestamp set to the same timezone as the dataframe df it works. However, the query approach, ie df.query("index>=timestamp"), is approx 4 times slower than df.idx[timestamp:] or df[timestamp:], where timestamp=pd.Timestamp('2012-11-7').tz_localize('Europe/Berlin')

Comment: timezone a make everything evaluate back in python so that's the cost; if it's a big enough series then it pays to deal in utc

Comment: intuitively this seems a lot of time to add 1 hour to go from utc+0 to utc+1 when considering timezones...Also, I was comparing the performance of the query indexing vs df.ix indexing both in the case of explicit timezones, and the querying is 4 times slower.