# How to subset pandas time series by time of day

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to subset a pandas time series that spans multiple days by time of day. E.g., I only want times between 12:00 and 13:00.

I know how to do this for a specific date, e.g.,

```
In [44]: type(test)
Out[44]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

In [23]: test
Out[23]:
                           col1
timestamp
2012-01-14 11:59:56+00:00     3
2012-01-14 11:59:57+00:00     3
2012-01-14 11:59:58+00:00     3
2012-01-14 11:59:59+00:00     3
2012-01-14 12:00:00+00:00     3
2012-01-14 12:00:01+00:00     3
2012-01-14 12:00:02+00:00     3

In [30]: test['2012-01-14 12:00:00' : '2012-01-14 13:00']
Out[30]:
                           col1
timestamp 
2012-01-14 12:00:00+00:00     3
2012-01-14 12:00:01+00:00     3
2012-01-14 12:00:02+00:00     3
```

But I have failed to do it for any date using `test.index.hour` or `test.index.indexer_between_time()` which were both suggested as answers to similar questions. I tried the following:

```
In [44]: type(test)
Out[44]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

In [34]: test[(test.index.hour >= 12) & (test.index.hour < 13)]
Out[34]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [col1]
Index: []

In [36]: import datetime as dt
In [37]: test.index.indexer_between_time(dt.time(12),dt.time(13))
Out[37]: array([], dtype=int64)
```

For the first approach, I have no idea what `test.index.hour` or `test.index.minute` are actually returning:

```
In [41]: test.index
Out[41]:
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2012-01-14 11:59:56, ..., 2012-01-14 12:00:02]
Length: 7, Freq: None, Timezone: tzlocal()

In [42]: test.index.hour
Out[42]: array([11, 23,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0], dtype=int32)

In [43]: test.index.minute
Out[43]: array([59, 50,  0,  0, 50, 50,  0], dtype=int32)
```

What are they returning? How can I do the desired subsetting? Ideally, how can I get both the two approaches above to work?

Edit: The problem turned out to be the the index was invalid, which is evidenced by `Timezone: tzlocal()` above, as `tzlocal()` should not be allowed as timezone. When I changed my method of generating the index to `pd.to_datetime()`, according to the final part of the accepted answer, everything worked as expected.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21512042/fast-selection-of-a-time-interval-in-a-pandas-dataframe-series/21512343#21512343 ?

Comment: your timezone is all loco, ``tzlocal()`` is not a timezone; how did you construct this index?

Comment: @Jeff: Thanks. I just noticed that the only apparent differences between my ``index`` and ones in ``working`` examples is the ``freq`` and ``Timezone``. My index was created with ``df.index = df['timestamp'].apply(dateutil.parser.parse)`` on strings like ``Sat Jan 14 11:01:38 GMT 2012``. I guess that's not working. Is a fix obvious?

Comment: Try just using `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])`

Comment: @David: Thanks, that works. Seems like my question is a bit useless without explaining my mistake. I am happy to do that if you would want to give that comment as an answer (e.g. at the start of your existing answer).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Assuming the index is a valid pandas timestamp, the following will work:

`test.index.hour` returns an array containing the hours for each row in your dataframe. Ex:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(randn(100000,1),columns=['A'],index=pd.date_range('20130101',periods=100000,freq='T'))
```

`df.index.year` returns `array([2013, 2013, 2013, ..., 2013, 2013, 2013])`

To grab all rows where the time is between 12 and 1, use

```
df.between_time('12:00','13:00')
```

This will grab that timeframe over several days/years etc. If the index is not a valid timestamp, convert it to a valid timestamp using `pd.to_datetime()`

Comment: That was my understanding before I tried it out. ``between_time('12:00','13:00')`` returns an empty ``data.frame`` and ``test.index.year`` returns ``array([2012, 2189, 1970, 1970, 1970, 1970, 2189], dtype=int32)``, not array([2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012]). And the examples in the question show that ``test.index.hour`` and ``test.index.minute`` do not return the hours and minutes of the rows respectively. Essentially, my question is, why is the behaviour not as you (and the docs) claim it should be; obviously I have missed something.