# timestamp from a txt file into an array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a txt file with the following structure:

```
"YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS.SSS val1 val2 val3 val4 val5'
```

The first line look like:

```
"2015/02/18 01:05:46.004   13.737306807  100.526088432   -22.2937   2   5"
```

I am having trouble to put the time stamp into the array. The time values are used to compare data with same timestamp from different files, parse the data for a specific time interval, and plotting purposes.

This is what I have right now ... except the time information:

```
dt=np.dtype([('lat', float), ('lon', float), ('height', float), ('Q', int), ('ns', int)]
a=np.loadtxt('tmp.pos', dt)
```

Any suggestion how to extent the *dt* to include the date and the time columns? or Is there a better way than using *loadtext* from *numpy*?

An example of the file can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/j69l8oeqdm73q8y/tmp.pos

**Edit 1**

It turns out that the [numpy.loadtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) takes a parameter called *converters* that may does the job:

```
a = np.loadtxt(fname='tmp.pos', converters={0: strpdate2num('%Y/%m/%d'), 1: strpdate2num('%H:%M:%S.%f')})
```

This means that the first two columns of a are 'date' and 'time' expressed as floats. To get back the time string, I can do something like this (though perhaps a bit clumsy):

```
In [441]: [datetime.strptime(num2date(a[i,0]).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')+num2date(a[i,1]).strftime('%H:%M:%S.%f'), '%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S.%f') for i in range(len(a[:,0]))]
```

which gives:

```
Out[441]: [datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 18, 1, 5, 46)]
```

However, the decimal part of the seconds are not preserved. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If this is coming from a text file, it may be simpler to parse this as text unless you want it all to end up in a numpy array. For example:

```
>>> my_line = "2015/02/18 01:05:46.004   13.737306807  100.526088432   -22.2937   2   5"
>>> datestamp, timestamp, val1, val2, val3, val4, val5 = [v.strip() for v in my_line.split()]
>>> datestamp
'2015/02/18'
>>> timestamp
'01:05:46.004'
```

So if you want to iterate over a file of these lines and obtain a native datetime object for each ine:

```
from datetime import datetime
with open('path_to_file', 'r') as my_file:
    for line in my_file:
        d_stamp, t_stamp, val1, val2, val3, val4, val5 = [v.strip() for v in my_line.split()]
        dt_obj = datetime.strptime(' '.join([d_stamp, t_stamp]), '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

Answer (score 0):

Better convert the time string in to timeStamp and pass the value as integer format. Integer will speed up your comparisons as well.

```
import time
dt, ts = "2015/02/18 01:05:46.004".split()
year,mon,day = [int(d) for d in dt.split('/')]
hrs,mins,secs = [int(float(d)) for d in ts.split(':')]
timeStamp = time.mktime((year,mon,day,hrs,mins,secs,0,0,time.localtime()[8]))
```

Answer (score 0):

[Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) is supposed to be good at this sort of thing. I'm no expert and had some trouble with the `parse_date` functionality of [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-read-csv-table) but the following seems to work reasonably well and fast:

```
import pandas as pd

names = ('date', 'time', 'lat', 'lon', 'height', 'Q', 'ns')
format = '%Y/%m/%d%H:%M:%S.%f'
df = pd.read_csv('tmp.pos', delim_whitespace=True, names=names)
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'] + df['time'], format=format)
```

---

If you want to select data based on time stamps, you can set it as the [index of the dataframe](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#datetimeindex):

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['date'] + df['time'], format=format)
print df['2015-02-18 2:30:00':'2015-02-18 2:30:10']
```

You can also set the time column as the index, but it seems directly slicing with only time is not supported:

```
format = '%H:%M:%S.%f'
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format=format)
print df['2:30:00':'2:30:10']  # prints empty DataFrame
```

But [you can use the following](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21627484/2379410):

```
print df.between_time('2:30:00','2:30:10')
```

Comment: How do I search for a specific timestamp? & How to I extract data between dt1 and dt2?

Comment: @AjanO, I've made an edit to my answer to address indexing a bit.

Comment: All right. Thanks. Now, I understand that _df_ is a dictionary data type and _DataFrame_ object is just another mapping key.

Comment: @moarrningsun, BTW do you know if [pandas.read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html) has any parameters to skip lines that start with a certain character similar to _comments_ parameter from [numpy.loadtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html). I tried to look at documentation could not figure up something that works dynamically.