# How to filter rows in Python pandas dataframe with duplicate values in the columns to be filtere

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Overall context:**

I have a data frame that contains observations for every five minute starting at 5 AM in the morning and ending at 8 PM in the evening for several days. I need to filter all the observations that start from 9 AM in the morning and end at 5 PM in the evening for every day.

the input data frame looks like this:

```
Date Time
2019-09-20 05:00:00,..,..
2019-09-20 05:05:00,..,..
...
2019-09-20 09:00:00,..,..
...
2019-09-20 17:00:00,..,..
2019-09-20 17:05:00,..,..
...
2019-09-20 20:00:00,..,..
2019-09-21 05:00:00,..,..
2019-09-21 05:05:00,..,..
...
2019-09-21 09:00:00,..,..
...
2019-09-21 17:00:00,..,..
2019-09-21 17:05:00,..,..
...
2019-09-21 20:00:00,..,..
```

and the output data frame should look like this:

```
2019-09-20 09:00:00,..,..
...
2019-09-20 17:00:00,..,..
2019-09-21 09:00:00,..,..
...
2019-09-21 17:00:00,..,..
```

**Steps taken so far**

In order to extract the rows between 9 am and 5 pm, I determined the number of seconds since midnight for every row by
extracting the hours, minutes and seconds using  vectorized data operations
so input dataframe will have column like

```
Date Time, Number of seconds since midnight
2019-09-20 05:00:00,xxxx,..,..
2019-09-20 05:05:00,yyyy,..,..
...
2019-09-21,05:00:00,xxxx,..,..
2019-09-21, 05:05:00,yyyy,..,..
```

Note that for the same time on every day, the number of seconds will remain the same
Now I was hoping to  extract alll the rows between 9 am and 5 pm by

```
df[(df['Number of seconds since midnight'] > (nseconds for 9 am from midnight)) &  ((df['Number of seconds since midnight'] < (nseconds for 5 pm from midnight))
```

but I get the rows ***from only the last date between*** 9am and 5 pm. 
TO me, it looks it is ignoring all the duplicate rows witht ehs ame calue.

Can anyone suggest a possible solution that does not iterate over each row and uses the vectorized operations as the database is very large

Comment: You can use d.hour ( d here is short for particular dateTime in the data) and check if there is any between 9 to 17(5pm), and store the valid ones in another dummy array (may be)

Comment: Look at the accepted answer on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21625850/how-to-subset-pandas-time-series-by-time-of-day. I think pd.between_time function is your answer

Answer (score 2):

Use dateTime.hour that is present in the dateTime object in your data, you could then filter the data based on which is greater than 9 and which is less than or equal to 5 or (17) and then add into your resulting data frame or array

The following piece of code might help you,

```
dummy = []
for d in dt:
    if d.hour>=9 and d.hour<=17: dummy.append(d)
print(dummy)
```

I have created my sample data from the following and it works on multiple dates too,

```
start = datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1)
dt = np.array([start + datetime.timedelta(hours=i) for i in range(24)])
```

Any corrections are welcomed.

Comment: Thank you for the response. However, I cannot accept it as an answer because the problem is that you mentioned that the date time object is present in the data, I don't clearly understand how it is because the data just contains a string. part of the problem as it turns out was to convert it into a pandas timestamp. The solution mentioned in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21625850/how-to-subset-pandas-time-series-by-time-of-day worked if you create the index on the date time column properly

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
from datetime import datetime

# Set Threshold
morning = datetime.strptime('9:00:00', "%H:%M:%S").time()
evening = datetime.strptime('17:00:00', "%H:%M:%S").time()

# Check conditions
check_cond = df['Time'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "%H:%M:%S").time() >= morning and datetime.strptime(x, "%H:%M:%S").time() <= evening)
df['True_False'] = check_cond

print(df[df['True_False'] == True])
```

**Result**
Retrieves the dataframe or assign it to another dataframe that meets above condition