# Calculate Python Average for Date & Time given Manually?

Tags: python, pandas, average

My Dataset:

Timestamp   Temperature
9/1/2016 0:00:08    53.8
9/1/2016 0:00:38    53.8
9/1/2016 0:01:08    53.8
9/1/2016 0:01:38    53.8
9/1/2016 0:02:08    53.8
9/1/2016 0:02:38    54.1
9/1/2016 0:03:08    54.1
9/1/2016 0:03:38    54.1
9/1/2016 0:04:38    54
9/1/2016 0:05:38    54
9/1/2016 0:06:08    54
9/1/2016 0:06:38    54
9/1/2016 0:07:08    54
9/1/2016 0:07:38    54
9/1/2016 0:08:08    54.1
9/1/2016 0:08:38    54.1
9/1/2016 0:09:38    54.1
9/1/2016 0:10:32    54
9/1/2016 0:11:02    54
9/1/2016 0:11:32    54
9/1/2016 0:00:08    54
9/2/2016 0:00:20    32
9/2/2016 0:00:50    32
9/2/2016 0:01:20    32
9/2/2016 0:01:50    32
9/2/2016 0:02:20    32
9/2/2016 0:02:50    32
9/2/2016 0:03:20    32
9/2/2016 0:03:50    32
9/2/2016 0:04:20    32
9/2/2016 0:04:50    32
9/2/2016 0:05:20    32
9/2/2016 0:05:50    32
9/2/2016 0:06:20    32
9/2/2016 0:06:50    32

```
from datetime import datetime  
import pandas as pd

def same_day(date_string):        
return datetime.strptime(date_string, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S").strftime('%m-%d')

df = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv', index_col=[0],parse_dates=[0], usecols=[0,1,2])
********calculate per day
print (df.index.strftime('%d%m%H'))
print (df.groupby([df.index.strftime('%d%m%H')]).mean())
```

Here ,How to export in json array Formate??

```
#****** exporting in CSV format
df.reset_index().to_csv('dataset.csv')
```

Now i want to give DATE Manually and check Average for 5 Hours and 10 Min for each DAY..like that..Where we can give date and time manually?? Please Help?

for an Eg:-
for Date 01-09-2016 10 min Avg is 36.08
for Date 02-09-2016 10 min Avg is 39.05

for Date 01-09-2016 5 hour Avg is 45.2
for Date 01-09-2016 5 hour Avg is 44.3

Like that for each date whatever date i give and whatever time i give..

With this below code i can find less than 2 min temperature:-

```
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv', parse_dates=['Timestamp'])
    #print (df)

    mask =  df.Timestamp.dt.minute < 2
    df1 = df[mask]

    df2 = df1.Timestamp.dt.date == pd.to_datetime('9/1/2016').date()
    print (df2)
```

for calculating Mean() :-

```
    df3 = df2.set_index('Timestamp', drop=False).resample('D').mean()
    print (df3)
```

Error is coming:-

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'set_index'
```

Comment: Filter the DataFrame for the *manually entered* date/time; sum the values for the desired time range(s); divide the total by the time.

Comment: Do some reading, look at the DataFrame documentation to see what is available, watch some videos, practice the examples that you find, learn how to filter a DataFrame, learn how to iterate over a DataFrame.  It is not entirely clear what you need, there are many details missing.  You show two different 5 hour averages for the same day, but that doesn't make any sense - There are more than two five hour periods in a day.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20233071/2823755,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21512343/2823755

Comment: still struggling..help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I created a DataFrame from your example data (I made the file tab delimited):

```
df = pd.read_csv('foo.csv',sep = '\t', header = 0,
                 parse_dates = [0], infer_datetime_format = True)
>>> df.head()
            Timestamp  Temperature
0 2016-09-01 00:00:08         53.8
1 2016-09-01 00:00:38         53.8
2 2016-09-01 00:01:08         53.8
3 2016-09-01 00:01:38         53.8
4 2016-09-01 00:02:08         53.8
>>>
```

Then I started reading the [Time Series/Date Functionality section of the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#time-series-date-functionality) and it seemed that it might be easier if the DataFrame index was a DateTime series - I also noticed some non sequential datetimes in the data so I sorted after setting the index (there are warnings in the docs about out-of-sequence datetimes):

```
df1 = df.set_index('Timestamp')
df1 = df1.sort_index()

>>> df1.head()
                     Temperature
Timestamp                       
2016-09-01 00:00:08         53.8
2016-09-01 00:00:08         54.0
2016-09-01 00:00:38         53.8
2016-09-01 00:01:08         53.8
2016-09-01 00:01:38         53.8
>>>
```

I didn't get too far down the documentation (practicing the examples as I read) till I stumbled upon a way to filter a datetime range:

```
>>> df1['2016-09-01 00:01:30' : '2016-09-01 00:03:15']
                     Temperature
Timestamp                       
2016-09-01 00:01:38         53.8
2016-09-01 00:02:08         53.8
2016-09-01 00:02:38         54.1
2016-09-01 00:03:08         54.1
>>>
```

That makes it really easy.  You can either assign the result to a name then get the mean or get the mean immediately:

```
>>> z = df1['2016-09-01 00:01:30' : '2016-09-01 00:03:15']
>>> z.mean()
Temperature    53.95
dtype: float64
>>> df1['2016-09-01 00:01:30' : '2016-09-01 00:03:15'].mean()
Temperature    53.95
dtype: float64
>>>
```

I stopped reading the docs there because it should be pretty easy to construct datetime strings for any time period starting, ending or surrounding a *manually entered* date/time

---

To be fair, a few weeks ago I got fed up with just stumbilng around trying to make Pandas do what I wanted so I watched the 'Pandas From The Ground Up' Pycon talk featured on the [*pandas* Talks page](http://pandas.pydata.org/talks.html#pandas-talks).  I don't even thing I watched the whole thing but what I did absorb increased my productivity immensely.

Comment: if i have multi columns then...like Temperature 1 and temperature 2 ??

Comment: i tried but not working..if it is two columns its giving combined Avg for both ...Main problem is when i am resample my df that time its giving me full avg..i am using:-
df1.resample('D').mean(axis=1)
its giving me combined Avg for my both column.

Comment: And one more thing ??? 
how to find missing timestamp..i want to find missing data ..my data is in every 30 second data and if some data is missing..how to find those data?

Comment: @NehaB - read the documentation, do some tutorials, practice the examples. Think about the problem and try to figure out a solution - keep it simple.